# Black / white theme, how to add fontawesome icon (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't really know JavaScript. My goal is to add the icons to the  white /  dark button. If you know javascript please help me.
What I want:

1. If you press the button it is white = moon.
2. If you press the button it is dark = sun.

My fontawesome icons:

1. `<i class="fa-solid fa-sun"></i>`
2. `<i class="fa-solid fa-moon"></i>`

CDN Font awesome:

`<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

```js
if (!localStorage.theme) localStorage.theme = "light"
document.body.className = localStorage.theme
toggleThemeBtn.innerText = document.body.classList.contains("dark") ? "white" : "dark"

toggleThemeBtn.onclick = () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark")
    toggleThemeBtn.innerText = document.body.classList.contains("dark") ? "white" : "dark"
    localStorage.theme = document.body.className || "light"
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    margin-top: 100px;
}
body.dark {
    background: #303133;
    color: #fff;
}
body.dark .content {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #1d2225;
}
body.dark button {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #1d2225;
    color: #fff;
}
body.dark button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1d2225;
}
body.dark button:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #1d2225;
}
.content {
    width: 55%;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px silver;
    padding: 20px;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px - 40px);
}
section:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.desc {
    margin: 10px 0;
    opacity: .7;
}
button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px silver;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px silver;
}
button:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px silver;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="content">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-sun nav-li-icon-bottom" id="moodBW"></i> <i class="fa-solid fa-moon nav-li-icon-bottom"></i>
        <section>
            <h1>BLock</h1>
            <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis quod porro voluptate minima quasi a mollitia dicta corrupti nesciunt! Corrupti, quis at? Perspiciatis voluptatibus provident laboriosam vitae voluptatem autem, cupiditate esse nihil est! Ducimus non, corrupti totam quisquam quod et!</p><button id="toggleThemeBtn">Сменить тему на тёмную</button>
        </section>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why but my HTML / CSS / js snippet doesn't work on StackOverflow, especially for this I created a page on CodePen
[codepen url](https://codepen.io/SergiuC121/pen/dyZWjOd)
or `https://codepen.io/SergiuC121/pen/dyZWjOd`

I don't know if it makes sense, but before I changed my code the following way and it practically worked but it displayed true and false after which I deleted the white/dark text.

```js
var i = document.createElement("i");
var t = document.createElement("i");
t.className = "fa-solid fa-moon nav-li-icon-bottom";
i.className = "fa-solid fa-sun nav-li-icon-bottom";
if (!localStorage.theme) localStorage.theme = "backgroundthemelight";
document.body.className = localStorage.theme;

    if (toggleThemeBtn.innerText = document.body.classList.contains("dark")) {
        document.getElementById('toggleThemeBtn').appendChild(i);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('toggleThemeBtn').appendChild(t);
    }

toggleThemeBtn.onclick = () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark");
    var i = document.createElement("i");
    i.className = "fa-solid fa-sun nav-li-icon-bottom";
    var t = document.createElement("i");
    t.className = "fa-solid fa-moon nav-li-icon-bottom";
    if (toggleThemeBtn.innerText = document.body.classList.contains("dark")) {
        document.getElementById('toggleThemeBtn').appendChild(i);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('toggleThemeBtn').appendChild(t);
    }
    localStorage.theme = document.body.className || "backgroundthemelight"
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    margin-top: 100px;
}

body.dark {
    background: #303133;
    color: #fff;
}

body.dark .content {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #1d2225;
}

body.dark button {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #1d2225;
    color: #fff;
}

body.dark button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #1d2225;
}

body.dark button:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #1d2225;
}

.content {
    width: 55%;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px silver;
    padding: 20px;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px - 40px);
}

section:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.desc {
    margin: 10px 0;
    opacity: .7;
}

button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px silver;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px silver;
}

button:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px silver;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="content"> 
                <i class="fa-solid fa-sun nav-li-icon-bottom" id="moodBW"></i> 
                <i class="fa-solid fa-moon nav-li-icon-bottom"></i>  
        <section>
            <h1>BLock</h1>
            <p class="desc">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis quod porro voluptate minima quasi a mollitia dicta corrupti nesciunt! Corrupti, quis at? Perspiciatis voluptatibus provident laboriosam vitae voluptatem autem, cupiditate esse nihil est! Ducimus non, corrupti totam quisquam quod et!
            </p>
            <button id="toggleThemeBtn">Сменить тему на тёмную</button>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Upstairs I presented my old code but here it doesn't work again I don't know why I attach a link to CodePen
[url codepen](https://codepen.io/SergiuC121/pen/zYPwLRz) or `https://codepen.io/SergiuC121/pen/zYPwLRz`

[image]

IMG result:
(suddenly the first button after pressing the 2nd button)

The theme is saved in local storage because I can't execute my snippet here.

Any advice?

**p.s:** I translated it into English with google translate if anyone finds mistakes please correct them so that others understand, thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me both the code pen examples are working fine and thus I am unable to propose a fix in Javascript. Though if your requirement is just to toggle between the btns and have the theme switched based on the same then you can make use of css to hide/show buttons and js can be used just to toggle body class.

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/MuditGarg/pen/PoOmdrp) example for the same.

The js in the pen is only for toggling the body class based on button clicked.
while css is doing the job of showing and hiding the buttons.

The JS is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("lightThemeBtn")?.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const body = document.querySelector("body");

    body.classList.add('dark');
});
document.getElementById("darkThemeBtn")?.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const body = document.querySelector("body");

    body.classList.remove('dark');
});
```

I have used all your css (except the padding on button) and added the following at the bottom:

```
.toggleThemeBtn > div > i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.toggleThemeBtn #darkThemeBtn {
  display:none;
}

body.dark #lightThemeBtn {
  display: none;
}

body.dark #darkThemeBtn {
  display: block;
}

.toggleThemeBtn > div {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Inside the HTML, in the button, I am rendering 2 div which contain the sun and the moon icon and text.

```
  <button class="toggleThemeBtn" id="toggleThemeBtn">
          <div id="lightThemeBtn"><i class="fa-solid fa-sun"></i>Light</div>          
          <div id="darkThemeBtn"><i class="fa-solid fa-moon" ></i>Dark</div>
        </button>
```

These changes are giving me the desired result. Hopefully it answers your question in a different way.

Comment: Your code helps me but not completely, if you noticed in my fragments it is saved in local storage, in your case it is not saved, I will try to find something to save it but I'm not very good at it, but thanks for the code. if you have the possibility, can you show me how to save in local storage?

Comment: Updated the [codepen](https://codepen.io/MuditGarg/pen/PoOmdrp).

It now saves the state inside  localStorage and loads the same on next reload.
The changes are only done on JS part.